# Is it grammatically incorrect to split two separate items as adj1, or adj2, noun? For example: adj1, or adj2, n = adj1 n and adj2 n

Tags: grammar, nouns, punctuation

I'm writing some content and a coworker stated that the following was incorrect:

*You have the option to use the red, or green, ball.*

or should I be saying:

*You have the option to use the red ball or the green ball.*

Is there one that is more grammatically correct than the other?

Comment: *the red or **the** green ball* makes it clear that there are two balls. Otherwise, it might be the case that there is only one ball of indeterminate color.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The typical construction for this sentence for a choice between two options is

> You have the option to use the red or green ball.

Commas can, however, be used for emphasis, including with your example.  For instance, if the normal choice of everyone is to use the red ball, you perhaps normally say "You have the option to use the red ball."  But if at the same time you wanted to *emphasize* that the choice of ball is not limited to the normally chosen color, you can offer "another option" offset with commas.

> You have the option to use the red, or green, ball.

Here's a longer example that could help clarify.

> You never care about my problems, Lisa.  All I need is someone to listen to me, but you're off having your own issues.  What I wouldn't give to have a good, or dysfunctional, friend right now.

Obviously the speaker would prefer a "good" friend.  But failing that, a "dysfunctional" one could be useful too.  Often an adverb is used to showcase the opposing option.

> You have the option to use the red, or even green, ball.

Answer (score 1):

If you put them the other way around, it is fully grammatical:

> You have the option to use the red ball, or the green.

The only way this could be confused is if somebody took "green" to be a noun, as in "putting green", but that seems fairly unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Your first option "*the red, or green, ball*." is awkward and to me borders on the grammatically incorrect.

Your second option "*the red ball or the green ball*." is absolutely correct but longer than it needs to be.

I would use "*the red or green ball*". There is no need to repeat "*the*" or "*ball*".